# How to authenticate in googleapi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, token, access-token

OK so I've received all the tokens and I want to access https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/

How do I do this - I've tried:

```
await (await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/" +
            userInfo.sub + '?access_token=' + accessToken, {method: "GET"})).json()
```

But it fails telling me I'm not logged in (401).

Comment: 401 what can we get the full error message.  Have you considered using the google apis js client library instead of doing this yourself?

Comment: It says "Login Required". I can't use the api js library since first I don't want to second I'm using node.

Comment: First if you are using node the one why is the question tagged JavaScript and not node.js.  Second why not use the Google apis node.js client library instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: Since I'm using fetch which universally works everywhere. But I don't want to use googleapis.

Comment: Directory is a Google API (GoogleAPIs) I am impressed that you were able to get an access token without using the Google client library.   Please add your authentication code if my answer does not help you.

Comment: It turned out accessToken in my case was an object with a token subobject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding it as a bearer token

**Javascript**

```
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users', { 
   method: 'get', 
   headers: new Headers({
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken, 
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   })
 });
```

**Node.js**

```
const request = require('request');

request({
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users',
  headers: {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
  },
  rejectUnauthorized: false
}, function(err, res) {
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log(res.body);
      }

});
```